# Prove that $\log:\Bbb C\setminus (-\infty,0]\to \Bbb R+i(-\pi,\pi)$ is continuous

Tags: analysis, proof-verification, continuity

> Prove that $\log:\Bbb C\setminus (-\infty,0]\to \Bbb R+i(-\pi,\pi)$ is continuous.

Can you check this proof?

I know that there is a unique representation for complex numbers in polar coordinates $z=|z|e^{i\alpha}$ for some $\alpha\in(-\pi,\pi]$. Following the comments if I proof that $\Bbb C\setminus(-\infty,0]$ is homeomorphic to $\Bbb R\times(-\pi,\pi)$ then the question is practically done.

Then I will show that the map $z\mapsto \langle |z|,\alpha\rangle$ is an homeomorphism. By a previous result we knows that the map

$$\Bbb C\setminus\{0\}\to(\Bbb R\setminus\{0\})\times S^1,\quad z\mapsto\langle |z|,\frac{z}{|z|}\rangle$$

is an homeomorphism, where $\frac{z}{|z|}=e^{i\alpha}$. And by a previous result we knows that

$$\arg:S^1\setminus\{-1\}\to(-\pi,\pi),\quad e^{i\alpha}\mapsto\alpha$$

is an homeomorphism too. Then the map $\langle |z|,e^{i\alpha}\rangle\mapsto\langle |z|,\alpha\rangle$ is an homeomorphism. Finally we have that

$$\Bbb C\setminus(-\infty,0]\cong(\Bbb R\setminus\{0\})\times(S^1\setminus\{-1\})\cong(\Bbb R\setminus\{0\})\times(-\pi,\pi)$$

And because the logarithm of a complex number is defined as the map $$\log:\Bbb C\setminus (-\infty,0]\to \Bbb R+i(-\pi,\pi),\quad z\mapsto \log |z|+i\alpha$$

it is enough to show that the map $\langle |z|,\alpha\rangle\mapsto \log|z|+i\alpha$ is continuous. Canonical projections and addition of continuous functions are continuous, and because the functions over the projections $|z|\mapsto \log |z|$ and $\alpha\mapsto i\alpha$ are continuous then we finally conclude that the logarithm of complex numbers is continuous.$\Box$

Comment: It appears to me that you are assuming to have already proven the hard part, but you are masking it amidst the "it's the same as" and stuff. Specifically, where did you prove exactly that the map $(-\pi,\pi)\to S^1\setminus\{-1\}$ given by $\alpha\mapsto e^{i\alpha}$ has a **continuous** inverse?

Comment: "Then we can says that $\Bbb C\setminus(-\infty,0]\cong \Bbb R\times(-\pi,\pi)$". If "$\cong$" means "homeomorphic to", then why can you say it? For one thing, the observation I did is substantially equivalent to the theorem.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli This is an isomorphism, I dont know if it is homeomorphic too. It is a different way to represent complex numbers i.e. $z\equiv |z|e^{i\alpha}$.

Comment: Isomorphism of what?

Comment: Oh, right...  $\Bbb C\setminus (\infty,0]$ It is not a vector space, right? Im thinking in an isomorphism between vector spaces but I realized now that $\Bbb C\setminus (\infty,0]$ is not a vector space... My bad. But I dont know what is needed to be prove that is an homeomorphism... I mean, it is just a different representation of the same elements.

Comment: Completeness has nothing to do with it. It's just that neither $\Bbb C\setminus(-\infty,0]$ not $\Bbb R\times(-\pi,\pi)$ are vector spaces.

Comment: You also need to prove that the map $\lvert z\rvert e^{i\alpha}\to e^{i\alpha}$ is continuous on $\Bbb C\setminus\{0\}$.

Comment: The second you said. The first thing you said comes from this misconceptions of yours that we could describe as "writing a complex number in the form $\beta e^{i\alpha}$ allows me to identify topologically $\Bbb R\times (-\pi,\pi)$ with $\Bbb C\setminus(-\infty,0]$". That not only is true, but it is what the theorem is asking you to prove. You just know that you have a bijective continuous map $(\beta,\alpha)\mapsto \beta e^{i\alpha}$, but this does not say that its inverse is continuous. When you say "the I use the projection on the second coordinate" you are implicitly [continues...]

Comment: ... saying that there is a continuous map $(\phi_1(\bullet),\phi_2(\bullet)):\Bbb C\setminus(-\infty,0]\to \Bbb R\times (-\pi,\pi)$ such that $\phi_1(z)e^{i\phi_2(z)}=z$. But this is basically what you need to prove: in fact, we could call that map $\phi_1(z)=e^{\operatorname{Re}\log z}$ and $\phi_2(z)=\operatorname{Im}\log z$ and call it a day.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli I updated the question, can you take a look please?